# Check the difference

Tags: c#, substring, filepath, difference

Hi I'm building a program that will look at files at have been placed into SVN and show what files have been changed in each commit.

As i'm only wanting to show the file path. if the path is that same I only want to show the difference.

example:

First file path is:

/GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1/DataModifier.cs

Second file path is:

/GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1/Tax Marker Ripper v1.csproj

What I'd like to do is substring at the point of difference.

So in this case:

/GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1/

would be substringed

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
     public string GetString(string Path1, string Path2)
    {

        //Split and Put everything between / in the arrays
        string[] Arr_String1 = Path1.Split('/');
        string[] Arr_String2 = Path2.Split('/');

        string Result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i <= Arr_String1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Arr_String1[i] == Arr_String2[i])
            {
              //Puts the Content that is the same in an Result string with /
                Result += Arr_String1[i] + '/';
                }

            else
                break;
        }
        // If Path is identical he would add a / which we dont want 
        if (Result.Contains('.'))
        {
            Result = Result.TrimEnd('/');
        }

        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: Note that I coded this so it will only detect the similarity between the two paths from the start of the string (reading left to right). If you want ANY similarity  you have to delete the else {break;}

Comment: This code will throw exception when Path1 have more fragments than Path2. It is also very slow.

Comment: Ohh yeah I see I will change it.

Comment: The thing about this code you've written is substring the part that is different I am looking to get the part that is different to be displayed

Comment: I thought that this what what you wanted but ok. Just turn it around its not that hard :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a loop. Basically:

```
 public String FindCommonStart(string a, string b)
    {
        int length = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);

        var common = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                common += a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                 break;
            }
        }

        return common;
    }
```

Comment: should edit if statement to this :
            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                common += a[i];
            }
            else
            {
               break;
            }

Comment: This code will not do the task because it does not respect path delimiters (/). And it is also slow, there is no need to allocate.

Comment: The thing about this code you've written is substring the part that is different I am looking to get the part that is different to be displayed

Comment: BTW, it will throw exception too, you should use Math.Min, not Math.Max.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public string GetCommonStart(string a, string b)
{
  if ((a == null) || (b == null))
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

  int Delim = 0;
  int I = 0;
  while ((I < a.Length) && (I < b.Length) && (a[I] == b[I]))
  {
    if (a[I++] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar) // or Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
      Delim = I;
  }

  return a.Substring(0, Delim);
}
```

Keep in mind, that this code is case-sensitive (and paths in windows in general are not).

Comment: Case sensitivity would be easily solved with a couple of `ToLower()` ;-)

Comment: ToUpper() is better, but my code sample only shows that question is actually very easy.

Comment: `ToUpper()` is better only for direct string comparisons (`ToUpperInvariant()` actually). It's not optimized for looping over the individual characters :-) I'd use `String.Compare` anyway for that, but that doesn't apply here. And yes, I understand what you wanted to show, just wanted to point that out because you stated the case sensitivity issue :-)